# Missing readline library when using make

Tags: 14.04, c++, make

I'm trying to compile ncmpcpp, and when I get to issuing the make command I get several errors such as:

```
/home/[myname]/ncmpcpp/src/window.cpp:329: undefined reference to `rl_bind_key'
/home/[myname]/ncmpcpp/src/window.cpp:144: undefined reference to `rl_point'
/home/[myname]/ncmpcpp/src/window.cpp:729: undefined reference to `readline'
```

And so on. It seems the problem is with the readline libraries and the libreadline-dev package, but I have already installed it from the official repos and I have the file /usr/include/readline/readline.h, which ncmpcpp includes in "window.cpp", so I don't really understand what's happening here.

Comment: Header files have little to do with undefined reference errors (which occur at link time, rather than compile time). Please include the actual compiler/linker (e.g. `gcc ...`) command from `make` that is resulting in these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `./autogen.sh` as described by the [manual](http://ncmpcpp.rybczak.net/download.php#others)?

Answer (score 0):

Makefile is (probably) broken, it seems to not link readline. I got it to work by adding `-lreadline` to `LDFLAGS`.
So, do this:

-find a line that starts with `LDFLAGS` in

```
/home/[myname]/ncmpcpp/Makefile
```

AND

```
/home/[myname]/ncmpcpp/src/Makefile
```

Here is the one that I found:

```
 LDFLAGS =  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_locale -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_thread -lmpdclient  -lpthread -lncursesw -ltinfo -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

Should be near line 260 in the `/ncmpcpp` dir and 225 in `/ncmpcpp/src`.

Then add

```
-lreadline
```

to it, somewhere where the other libraries are. I have it in between `-lmpdclient` and `-lpthread`, so that it becomes

```
LDFLAGS =  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_locale -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_thread -lmpdclient -lreadline -lpthread -lncursesw -ltinfo -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

After that just `make` and hope for the best, and if that works, continue as per instructions.

Best of luck!